# uploadify queueData error

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I am using Uploadify 3.1 and am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'queueData' of undefined" when clicking the upload button. Below is my code. Not sure what the problem is.

Upload field:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload"/>
<input type="button" class="batchImport" value="Upload Files"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click",".batchImportElements",function(){
        $("#objectDetails").hide().html("");
        $("#objectList").show();
        $("#objectList").html("<img src="images/loading.gif"/> Loading").show();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:{
                multiple:1
            },
            url:"/index.php/elements_handler/importElements",
            success:function(response){
                checkResponse(response);
                $("#objectList").html(response);

                $("#file_upload").uploadify({
                    "swf":"/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf",
                    "uploader":"/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.php",
                    "uploadFolder":"/uploads/",
                    "auto":false,
                    "multi":true,
                    "height":19,
                    "width":94,
                    "onUploadError":function(file,errorCode,errorMsg,errorString){
                        alert("The file " + file.name + " could not be uploaded: " + errorString);
                    },
                    "onUploadSuccess":function(file, data, response){
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            data:{
                                multiple:1,
                                companies_id:companies_id,
                                file:file,
                                data:data,
                                folderPath:1
                            },
                            url:"/index.php/elements_handler/importElements",
                            success:function(response){
                                checkResponse(response);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                $(document).on("click",".batchImport",function(){
                    $(".batchImport").uploadify("upload");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

`

The `$('.batchImport')` is the button being used to fire the upload. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the batchImport get on the file control because in the code you pasted it does not have it yet?

Comment: I added it as well now so you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating uploadify on the file control with the id **file_upload** then calling the upload on the button control with the class **batchImport**? The button with class **batchImport** was not setup as an uploadify control so it should throw an error.

```
// Your code
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
    ....                    
});

$(".batchImport").uploadify("upload");


// Should most likely be
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
    ....                    
});

$("#file_upload").uploadify("upload");
```

Comment: Thank you Josh! I did not see I had called upload on the wrong element. It works now.

Comment: One more question, do you know how to make uploadify upload all the files queud when you click the button, rather than 1 at a time?

Comment: I usually have it set to auto-upload so I have never had to deal with that before. If I have time, I may look into it.